# RStudioError in names(x) <- value : 'names' attribute [15] must be the same length as the vector [1]

Tags: r

I'm trying to name some of my column's, but I keep getting this error.

```
colnames(data) <- c(
"symbol",
"number",
"nr_pix",
"RowWith2",
"RowWith3OrMore",
"colWith2",
"colWith3OrMore",
"width",
"left2tile",
"height",
"right2tile",
"verticalness",
"bottom2tile",
"top2tile",
"horizontalness"
)
```

Comment: what is `length(colnames(data))`?

Comment: Do you mean what length is it??

Comment: how many columns has data? what is the value of `length(colnames(data))`

Comment: There's 15 columns in the csv file that i'm trying to name

Comment: Can you tell us the results of `ncol(data)`?

Comment: The result of ncol(data) is [1] 1

Comment: It seems that the number of columns names is not equal to the number of columns in `data`. Would suggest you recheck the number of columns and the number of column names.